# SQL query to fetch employee name and average salary

Tags: sql, sql-server

For an `Employee` table with columns `EmpId`, `Name`, `Salary`, is it possible to write a SQL query so that the result contains each employee's name and the average salary of all employees?

**Sample Data**

```
EmpId      Name       Salary 
 1         Alice       12000
 2         Bob         12000 
 3         Charlie     10000 
 4         Doug         6000
```

I need a query which would return this result:

**Result**

```
Name       AvgSalary 
Alice      10000 
Bob        10000 
Charlie    10000 
Doug       10000
```

Here 10000 is average salary of all the 4 employees.

Comment: Please share what you tried so far.

Comment: This is silly. Run one query that calculates the average salary for all employees, and then you can simply SELECT Name, 10000 as AvgSalary FROM Whatever. It makes no sense to do so, because it's not that employee's average salary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you're just getting the average of all salaries along with the list of every employee.  You don't have to compute it each time, and that would actually be wasteful to do so, but you could just do this:

```
SELECT Name, (SELECT AVG(Salary) FROM SampleData) AS AvgSalary
FROM SampleData
```

Otherwise, you could just get the average salary once:

```
DECLARE @AVGSALARY float
SET @AVGSALARY = (SELECT AVG(Salary) FROM SampleData)

SELECT Name, @AvgSalary AS AvgSalary
FROM SampleData
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a window function for this, but the subquery in the SELECT should be faster:

```
SELECT name, avg(salary) OVER () as avgSal FROM SampleData;
```

Comment: You can just say `over ()`

Comment: "Over"  I didn't know that one. Sneaky! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct name, average from sampledata
 cross join
(select avg(salary) average from sampledata) a1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name, AVG(Salary) 
FROM SampleData
GROUP BY Name
```

Comment: This is not the average of all the employees. This is the average for each employee individually.

Comment: Yes. Yes it will. And Avg(Salary) will return distinct employee's average salary. Which is not what was asked for. OP asked for the average of all the employee's salaries.